# asp.net mvc 5 is redirecting to the login page when accessing Authorize action with authenticated user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have actions which are accessible both by Authenticated and Guest User. So I have marked my controller and actions as

```
namespace FlightManagementV1.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class SearchFlightGuestController : Controller
    {
        // GET: SearchFlightGuest
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult SearchFlightGuest()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SearchFlightGuest1(FlightScheduleModel obj)
        {
            CustomerHelper helper = new CustomerHelper();
            List<FlightScheduleModel> list = helper.SearchFlightGuest(obj);
            if (list.Count == 0)
            {
                TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Sorry!!! We are unable to find any matching Flight for you.";
                return RedirectToAction("SearchFlightGuest", "SearchFlightGuest");
            }
            return View(list);
        }
    }
}
```

The View `SearchFlightGuest1` has a link which redirects to an action marked by `[Authorize]` attribute. In case of Guest Users link is automatically redirecting to the login page but in case of Authenticated users, the link is also redirecting to the login page and not accessing action marked by `[Authorize]` attribute.

View `SearchFlightGuest1`

```
<h3>We have found following flights for you</h3>

<br />
<table border="1" style="background-color : white; font-weight : normal">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Flight ID")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Departure Place")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Destination Place")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Departure Date and Time")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Arrival Date and Time")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Premium Fare (Rs)")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("First Fare (Rs)")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Economy Fare (Rs)")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Available (Premium)")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Available (First)")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Available (Economy)")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Distance (KM)")
        </th>
            <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightId)
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepPlace)
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DestPlace)
        </td>
        <td class="field-datetime">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartureDT)
        </td>
        <td class="field-datetime">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArrivalDT)
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FarePremium)
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FareFirst)
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FareEconomy)
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AvailablePremium)
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AvailableFirst)
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AvailableEconomy)
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Distance)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Book Journey", "BookingDetails", "BookJourney", item, new { })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Action i am trying to access

```
    public class BookJourneyController : Controller
    {
        // GET: BookFlight
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult BookingDetails(FlightScheduleModel schedule)
        {
            FlightJourneyViewModel journeyViewModel = new FlightJourneyViewModel();
            journeyViewModel.flightSchedule = schedule;
            Session["flight_id"] = schedule.FlightId;
            return View(journeyViewModel);
        }
}
```

Comment: Your code is not really showing what your text describes. Show us the parts of the Razor View and include the Action you're redirecting to please

Comment: Which code you are using to redirect users depends on `[Authorize]` attribute?